# Which function gives a better approximation to $\pi(x)?$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

The [Logarithmic integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function), $\text{Li}(x),$ is asymptotic to the [Prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function), $\pi(x):$

$$\text{Li}(x)=\int_2^x \frac{1}{\log t}~dt $$

Another function, $\text{F}(x),$ is asymptotic to $\pi(x):$

$$ \text{F}(x)=\frac{1}{\log x}\int_2^x e^{\frac{1}{\log t}} ~dt$$

> How do you prove which function gives a better approximation to $\pi(x)?$

I think looking at $\text{Li}(x)-\pi(x)$ vs. $\text{F}(x)-\pi(x)$ might work. I found that $\text{F}(x)<\text{Li}(x)$ for $x>90.$

Comment: You may show that $$
F(x) = \frac{x}{{\log x}} + \frac{x}{{\log ^2 x}} + \frac{3}{2}\frac{x}{{\log ^3 x}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{x}{{\log ^4 x}}} \right) = \operatorname{Li}(x) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{x}{{\log ^3 x}}} \right).
$$ But $$
\left| {\pi (x) - \operatorname{Li}(x)} \right| = o\!\left( {\frac{x}{{\log ^k x}}} \right)
$$ for any positive integer $k$. $F(x)$ is much worse, since by the above two,  $$
\left| {\pi (x) - F(x)} \right| = \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{x}{{\log ^3 x}}} \right).
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(x) \leq \frac{1}{\ln x} \int \limits_{2}^{x} 1+ \frac{1}{\ln t}+ \frac{1}{\ln^2 t} dt = \frac{1}{\ln x}(x - \frac{x}{\ln x} +2  Li(x)) $

And so $ \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} (F(x)-Li(x))\frac{\ln^4 x}{x} \leq -2$

Yet According to PNT $ \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} (\pi(x)-Li(x))\frac{\ln^4 x}{x} = 0$

So $F(x) < \pi(x), Li(x)$ and its not a better approximation to $\pi(x)$ than $Li(x)$